# virtualbox Second monitor on Ubuntu guest disappears after black screen timeout

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, 22.04, virtualbox, multiple-monitors

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 as host and an Ubuntu 20.04 as guest on it using virtualbox both with two monitors.
When I am not around for a while and the screen turns black, I need to click or press a key to get the screen back again.
After the screen gets back, the second monitor of the guest disappears.
I need to go for full screen and get back to maximized screen to see the second monitor again.